# How to remove Font Awesome symbol code from bookmarks?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, fontawesome

LaTeX:

```latex
\section{\faicon{cogs}\ Technical Skills}
```

Bookmark:

```
"F085 Technical Skills
```

How to remove the symbol code `"F085`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `hyperref`, `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\faicon#1{}}` should do...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, this works! But why do you mention `hyperref`? I'm a newbie...

Comment: I posted an answer with a better definition. I mentioned `hyperref` because it's the most common (if not the only) package for hyperlinking a LaTeX document. If you have pdf bookmarks you probably have `hyperref` loaded.

Comment: By the way, you don't need “backslash space”; `\faicon{cogs} Technical Skills` works as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hyperref` provides the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`, which is a hook to execute commands before `hyperref` tries to translate TeX code into pdf strings. The argument of `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` is arbitrary TeX code which should redefine commands which don't expand to valid pdf strings. You can redefine `\faicon` to consume an argument and do nothing:

```latex
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faicon#1{}%
}
```

However with that setup, the two sections:

```latex
\section{\faicon{cogs}\ Technical Skills}
\section{Technical Skills}
```

would produce the bookmarks (note the space):

```
 Technical Skills
Technical Skills
```

perhaps a better setting would be:

```latex
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faicon#1{\ignorespaces}%
}
```

so that spaces after `\faicon{whatever}` disappear.

Minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\faicon#1{\ignorespaces}}

\begin{document}
\section{\faicon{cogs}\ Technical Skills}
\section{Technical Skills}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this also works if you're using the shorthand for each icon, e.g., `\faUsers`